# How to hook into the Asp.Net Core 6 MVC route system to customize urls generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-6.0

In the old .Net Framework MVC implementations, I was creating routes by myself so that I could also influence urls generation. Part of the code:

```cs
public class RouteBase : Route
{
    public RouteBase(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, routeHandler) { }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if (Url.Contains("{segment}") && !values.ContainsKey("segment"))
            values["segment"] = requestContext.HttpContext.Items["segmentValue"];

        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
    }
}
```

Thanks to GetVirtualPath, I was able to detect a particular segment in the route template and inject a proper value in the route values dictionary so that the client app did not have to specify it when calling for instance Url.RouteUrl(routeName).

In asp.net core 6, I'm now using attributes based routing and I don't know how to hook into this so that I can inject some value into the route values dictionary when I generate urls. If I have a route template like so:

```cs
[Route("{segment}/test", Name = "name"]
```

When I call this, I want an injection mechanism from somewhere else in the code so that the known segment value is injected into the route values used to build the url:

```cs
var url = Url.RouteUrl("name"); // Not passing new { segment = value } as second param
```

For information, I simply use this in Startup:

```cs
app.MapControllers();
```

Comment: Asp.Net Core has a similar interface called `IRoute`, Have you tried to use it? In my opinion, if you want to make some judgments with URL before enters the action, you can customize a middleware to do this,

Comment: @XinranShen Well, after all, I don't think a middleware will be able to help relatively to url generation. Middleware are used when there is an incoming request. Here I want to hook into Url.RouteUrl for instance so that I can add a value into the route values dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amir's answer put me on track to find a solution (bounty award for him). Creating a custom UrlHelper was the way to go, but not with a UrlHelper derived class. For enpoint routing, the framework is using the sealed [EndpointRoutingUrlHelper](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/EndpointRoutingUrlHelper.cs) class. So I just needed to derive from UrlHelperBase, paste the code from EndpointRoutingUrlHelper and add my customizations. I was lucky that there were no internal pieces of code in there...

Here is the solution. Note that:

- the term "segment" mentioned in the original question is replaced by what I actually have in my code i.e. "lang".
- HttpContext.Items["lang"] is set by a middleware.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// The custom UrlHelper is registered with serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IUrlHelperFactory, LanguageAwareUrlHelperFactory>();
public class LanguageAwareUrlHelperFactory : IUrlHelperFactory
{
    private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;
    public LanguageAwareUrlHelperFactory(LinkGenerator linkGenerator)
    {
        _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }

    public IUrlHelper GetUrlHelper(ActionContext context)
    {
        return new LanguageAwareUrlHelper(context, _linkGenerator);
    }
}

// Source code is taken from https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Routing/EndpointRoutingUrlHelper.cs
// and modified to inject the desired route value
public class LanguageAwareUrlHelper : UrlHelperBase
{
    private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

    public LanguageAwareUrlHelper(ActionContext actionContext, LinkGenerator linkGenerator) : base(actionContext)
    {
        if (linkGenerator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(linkGenerator));

        _linkGenerator = linkGenerator;
    }

    public override string? Action(UrlActionContext urlActionContext)
    {
        if (urlActionContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(urlActionContext));

        var values = GetValuesDictionary(urlActionContext.Values);

        if (urlActionContext.Action == null)
        {
            if (!values.ContainsKey("action") && AmbientValues.TryGetValue("action", out var action))
                values["action"] = action;
        }
        else
            values["action"] = urlActionContext.Action;

        if (urlActionContext.Controller == null)
        {
            if (!values.ContainsKey("controller") && AmbientValues.TryGetValue("controller", out var controller))
                values["controller"] = controller;
        }
        else
            values["controller"] = urlActionContext.Controller;

        if (!values.ContainsKey("lang") && ActionContext.HttpContext.Items.ContainsKey("lang"))
            values["lang"] = ActionContext.HttpContext.Items["lang"];

        var path = _linkGenerator.GetPathByRouteValues(
            ActionContext.HttpContext,
            routeName: null,
            values,
            fragment: urlActionContext.Fragment == null ? FragmentString.Empty : new FragmentString("#" + urlActionContext.Fragment));

        return GenerateUrl(urlActionContext.Protocol, urlActionContext.Host, path);
    }

    public override string? RouteUrl(UrlRouteContext routeContext)
    {
        if (routeContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(routeContext));

        var langRouteValues = GetValuesDictionary(routeContext.Values);
        if (!langRouteValues.ContainsKey("lang") && ActionContext.HttpContext.Items.ContainsKey("lang"))
            langRouteValues.Add("lang", ActionContext.HttpContext.Items["lang"]);

        var path = _linkGenerator.GetPathByRouteValues(
            ActionContext.HttpContext,
            routeContext.RouteName,
            langRouteValues,
            fragment: routeContext.Fragment == null ? FragmentString.Empty : new FragmentString("#" + routeContext.Fragment));

        return GenerateUrl(routeContext.Protocol, routeContext.Host, path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create and register a custom UrlHelper. It will give you the ability to manipulate the behavior as per your use case:

```
public class CustomUrlHelper : UrlHelper
{
    public CustomUrlHelper(ActionContext actionContext)
        : base(actionContext) { }

    public override string? RouteUrl(UrlRouteContext routeContext)
    {
        // if(routeContext.RouteName == "name" && routeContext.Values....)
        // routeContext.Values = ....
        return base.RouteUrl(routeContext);
    }
}

public class CustomUrlHelperFactory : IUrlHelperFactory
{
    public IUrlHelper GetUrlHelper(ActionContext context)
    {
        return new CustomUrlHelper(context);
    }
}
```

and in your Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUrlHelperFactory, CustomUrlHelperFactory>();
```

Then by calling the Url.RouteUrl("name"), your CustomUrlHelper will be called.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it and unfortunately, I get this exception in base.RouteUrl(routeContext): InvalidOperationException:  Could not find an IRouter associated with the ActionContext. If your application is using endpoint routing then you can get a IUrlHelperFactory with dependency injection and use it to create a UrlHelper, or use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.LinkGenerator.

Comment: Your answer helped my find the solution. See my accepted answer. Of course I credit the bounty award to you.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net Core, I use the below two methods and it is able to successfully generate the URL.

```
[Route("{segment}/test", Name = "name"]

var url1 = Url.RouteUrl("name", new { segment = "aa" });
var url2 = Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { segment = "aa" });
```

[image]

Comment: As explained in my post, I don't want to pass the segment in all calls to RouteUrl. Its value is global and not contextual to the current request. So I need to inject it at another level.